# Insert or Update in one Query API and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs, api

I have a product that can be edited and add a language. In my current api, if there is already a language, it can be displayed and can be updated but my problem is if there is no additonal details for example, and I input a new one when i edited it, the data is not saved on the database.

```
if(!empty($body['addtl'])){
        $ProdArray = "";
        foreach($body['addtl'] as $value){
            foreach($value as $key => $innerValue){
                    if($key!="id")
                        if(!empty($innerValue))
                            $ProdArray .= $key."='".$innerValue."', ";
            }

            $ProdArray = trim($ProdArray, ", ");
            $ProdArray .= " WHERE id=".$value['id'];
            $sql_query = "UPDATE ProductAddtlDetails SET ".$ProdArray;
            $stmt = $dbRemote->prepare($sql_query);
            $stmt->execute();
            $ProdArray = "";
        }
        $editFlag = 1;
    }
```

How can I solve my issue?

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: I don't see any error checking here. Did the query work? Did it blow up? You need to find out. The easiest way to do this is to enable exceptions with whatever driver you're using.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we can enable the error mode so you can put this after your connection :

```
$dbRemote->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

then change your code to this:

```
if(!empty($body['addtl'])){
   $ProdArray = "";
   foreach($body['addtl'] as $value){
     foreach($value as $key => $innerValue){
          if($key!="id" && !empty($innerValue)) {
            $ProdArray .= $key."=". $innerValue. ", ";
          }
     }
   $ProdArray = rtrim($ProdArray, ", ");
   $ProdArray .= " WHERE id=".$value['id'];
   $sql_query = "UPDATE ProductAddtlDetails SET ".$ProdArray;
   $stmt = $dbRemote->prepare($sql_query);
   $stmt->execute();
   $ProdArray = "";
   }
     $editFlag = 1;
 }
```

Comment: still not saving data

Comment: @bleykFaust have u imported your connection